# Spring, db and property file configuration

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

I have some JDO objects that I want to spring to configure with info from a property file.

But since spring isn't used to create (i.e these objects are not listed as beans in the xml.  Should they, how would it look?) these objects how can I get it to configure those objects?

Only solution I can come up with is to have the property file info configured into the dao and then have the dao insert that data into the object before it returns it.  Or I guess I can do some AOP magic, but that seems heavy handed and I don't think it will work in Google App Engine where this service will be deployed.

Any other advice.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If you want to set values of a JDO object, why don't you load them from the datastore? What's the point of the property file?

Comment: Removed tag for JDO, since JDO is the persistence mechanism but imposes no constraints on an object, being what some refer to as a POJO, hence the problem has nothing to do with JDO; it's simply one of Spring beans

Answer (score 1):

You can put *any bean* in applicationContext.xml, and configure all of its properties there.
The properties file can be loaded via:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
```

and then, on your bean definition:

```
<property name="propertyName" value="${valueFromPropertiesFile}" />
```

Then, in order to have the properly configured bean, you will have to inject it - either in the applicationContext.xml, or via `@Resource` / `@Autowired`

But if you can't let spring create, and configure your beans, then simply populate them with your properties manually - load a properties file with `java.util.Properties`, and fill the data needed.

Comment: The JDO object couldn't be injected, it is created by the DAO and there will be more than one so how could spring know which to inject?

Comment: well, then you can't use spring. You must fill your objects at the moment you instantiated them. Load your properties manually.

Comment: He could actually by providing a stateful Spring bean factory. However usually that sort of things falls under the category of forcing the use of technology for the sake of the technology itself instead of actual need so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: yes, you are correct. instantiating domain objects from within a managed context is not a common practice, I think.

Answer (score 0):

> I have some JDO objects that I want to spring to configure with info from a property file.

I don't get the whole idea. Are these objects persistent or not? If they are, just load them from the datastore. If not, they aren't really JDO objects as pointed out in comments. And in that case, I don't understand the point of the DAO and of the property file. Why don't you just declare them as Spring beans?